# ckeditor inserting extra </br>

Tags: java, ckeditor

I need a help please. I am using CKEditor for rich text editor. I am setting the configurations as below in the jsp.

```
cKEditorConfig = new CKEditorConfig();
cKEditorConfig.addConfigValue("autoParagraph", false);
cKEditorConfig.addConfigValue("basicEntities",false);
```

I am getting a issue that the editor is placing extra < br/ > in side the html after submission of the page. There are options to do that as below:
    // Inserts a line break after the

opening tag.
    breakAfterOpen : true,

1. How can I achieve this is the config settings in jsp
2. How can I change enterMode from < p > to < br > using this java setting configuration

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 2 nd problem is resolved by usingcKEditorConfig.addConfigValue("enterMode", 2);

Comment: Are you using a CKEditor (integrating with a CKFinder) from [this](http://ckeditor.com/) site?

Comment: yes, I am using this site. for java based application

Comment: For example, if I submit xxx<br/>yyy, after submission it is becoming xxx<br/><br/>yyy

Comment: Can you clarify question 1? Maybe a specific example of what happens and what you would like to happen. Show the WYSIWYG content and the Source view content before submission and after submission along with what you would like to work differently.

Comment: Hi  codewaggle, This is what happening,before submission: xxx<br/>yyy, after submission: xxx<br/><br/>yyy . i.e. one extra <br/>added in between.

Comment: Do I need to remove any plugin? if yes, which plugin and how to do it?

Comment: Hi, can anybody help me with this.

Comment: You might want to try this.http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/3260 and post this issue in CKeditor website.After FCKEditor upgraded to CkEditor this is the major Issue.You can raise an ticket here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ckeditor-tickets or another option is you can directly send your question to CKEditor support here http://ckeditor.com/support.Some times if you have luck they will answer directly.